# Render Method Called Twice

Tags: liferay-7

I am facing a problem.When i am calling my portlet so render method is triggered twice .I got a link where i got to know that is because of custom theme.

> https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/24734463

I am also using custom theme for my portlet.Can anyone provide solution how to prevent to render twice with custom theme?

Note- I am using liferay-7

Comment: Incident for this issue - https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-40984, Please check any solution found here

Comment: I went through that link too but not able to find solution @user2249207